# AWSCLIで、s3のバケット内にある全バージョンのファイルを削除するコマンドはありますか？

Tags: aws, amazon-s3

S3のバケットを削除する必要があり、下記の処理をコマンドで実行したいです。

1. S3の管理画面からversionをhideからshowに変えて全てのバージョンを表示（http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonS3/latest/UG/managing-objects-versioned-bucket.html を参考）
2. 全てのファイルを選択して削除
3. 空になったバケットを削除

awsコマンドで下記を実行してみたのですが、まだファイルが残っていて、全てのバージョンを削除して欲しいとエラーが返ってきます。

```
$ aws rm s3://(バケット名) --recursive
$ aws rb s3://(バケット名) --force

remove_bucket failed: s3://(バケット名)/ An error occurred (BucketNotEmpty) when calling the DeleteBucket operation: The bucket you tried to delete is not empty. You must delete all versions in the bucket.
```

管理画面を見てもlsコマンドを打っても空ですが、管理画面のversionを表示に切り替えると見えるのでこのファイルの事だと思います。
（削除ファイルが大きいせいか、現在も削除中で終わりが見えていません。）

rmコマンドには、バージョンを指定するオプションはありません。
他の方法があるのでしょうか？

Comment: [FYI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonS3/latest/dev/delete-or-empty-bucket.html#empty-bucket-awscli)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

バージョンを有効にしたS3バケットを削除する際は、ライフサイクル設定により全バージョンファイルが消えるよう設定する必要があります。

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonS3/latest/dev/delete-or-empty-bucket.html#delete-bucket-lifecycle

S3コンソールのbucketのプロパティからライフサイクルの設定でprefixを空欄（バケット全体でもたぶんOK）、日数1でオブジェクト生成後１日たっているファイルがすべて削除されます。
※以前のバージョンは上書き実行日/有効期限終了日から 1 日後

このライフサイクル設定はコマンドラインからも設定可能です。

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-lifecycle.html

```
aws s3api put-bucket-lifecycle --bucket ${backet_name} --lifecycle-configuration file://lifecycle.json
```

lifecycle.jsonは以下のようになります。

```
{
  "Rules": [
    {
      "Expiration": {
        "Days": 1
      },
      "NoncurrentVersionExpiration": {
        "NoncurrentDays": 1
      },
      "ID": "Delete all",
      "Prefix": "",
      "Status": "Enabled"
    }
  ]
}
```

上記設定で全ファイルが消えれば普通にバケットを削除できます。

今のところ1日後設定が最速のようですが、Python等の言語からAPIを呼び出して削除する方法もあるようです。

コード例が以下の質問の回答にあります。（英語ですがコード例は問題ないかと）

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29809105/how-do-i-delete-a-versioned-bucket-in-aws-s3-using-the-cli

Comment: ありがとうございます。ライフサイクルを試してみたのですが、消えないです。pythonの方もやってみました。ただ、バージョンが古いようで自分の方でドキュメントを参考に試してみたのですが、削除実行されているとは思うものの進捗がわからず、タイムアウトもせず。。。放置しても反応がないので別の方法を探しています。

Comment: @default 失礼しました。lifecycle.jsonに過去バージョン用の設定NoncurrentVersionExpirationが抜け落ちていました。動作確認したものに回答を編集しましたのでご確認ください。